# Improper integral problem.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

How to find divergence/convergence condition for $p$ on

$$\int\limits_{2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{{(\ln x)}^p} \, \mathrm d x$$

I tried comparison test , but failed.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) and [here](https://www.ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/107/Series/inttest.htm).

Comment: For any $p>0$ and any $x$ big enough we have $\log(x)^p\leq x$ hence the integral is always diverging.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Could you turn your comment into an answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $\ln(x)=t$. We then have $x=e^t$, i.e., $dx=e^tdt$. Hence, we have the integral to be
$$\int_{\ln(2)}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^tdt}{t^p}$$
which clearly diverges for all $p$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p\leqslant 0$, the integral is divergent because the integrand is greater than $1$ if $x\geqslant e$.

If $p\lt 0$, then $\int_t^{2t}\frac 1{(\log x)^p}\mathrm dx\geqslant \frac t{(\log(2t))^p}  $; if $\int_2^{\infty}\frac 1{(\log x)^p}\mathrm dx$ was convergent, then we would have $\lim_{t\to\infty}  \int_t^{2t}\frac 1{(\log x)^p}\mathrm dx=0$, which is not the case.